# Configure a Wildfly 10 MSQL datasource in OpenShift v3

Tags: mysql, wildfly-10, openshift-origin

I have an application currently working on my local Dev machine. It uses Wildfly 10, MySQL 5.7 and Hibernate. My application looks for the 'AppDS' datasource from within Wildfly.

I've created a Wildfly 10 container and a MySQL container on OpenShift V3. Typically, I would log into Wildfly and configure a datasource, but all that configuration is lost when a container restarts. I thought it would be a matter of finding my connection environment settings, and using the pre-configured database connections, but I can't find what the variables should be set to, and the default connections don't work without them.

I downloaded and read OpenShift for Developers, but they side-step the issue by creating a direct database connection, rather than going through a datasource.

exporting the environment variables failed because 'no matches for apps.openshift.io/, Kind=DeploymentConfig'. Is the book out of date? Are they not using deployment config to store environment variables?

I would appreciate it greatly if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a project running locally on my machine that uses Wildfly 10, Mysql 5.7 and Hibernate. I found the documentation to be incomplete. After a few days of working with it, I have figured out how to deploy a simple J2EE project with this stack.

I am updating my question with the step-by-step I wish I'd had. I hope this saves someone some time in the future.

1. create new openshift user
2. create project dbtest
3. add MySQL to dbtest project:
   The following service(s) have been created in your project: mysql:

   Username: test
      Password: test
   Database Name: testdb
   Connection URL: mysql://mysql:3306/
4. add Wildfly to the project:

oc login https://api.starter-us-west-1.openshift.com 
oc project dbtest
oc status

5. scale current wildfly pod to 0. (you won't have enough CPU to run 3 pods, and redeploy tries to start a new one and hot swap them)
6. From left menu: Applications->Deployments->(dbtest)Wildfly10 pod->environment(tab)-> add: 
   MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb 
   MYSQL_DB_ENABLED=true
   MYSQL_USER:test
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
7. push wildfly pod back to 1.
8. use terminal in Wildfly to run ./add-user.sh
9. oc port-forward wildfly10-6-rkr58 :9990 (replace wildfly10-6-rkr58 with your pod name, found by clicking on the running pod [circle with a 1 in it] and noting the pod name in the upper left corner])
10. login to Wildfly from 127.0.0.1: and test the MySQLDS. It should now connect.

Comment: To avoid problem with (5), you should switch your Wildfly application from Rolling deployment strategy to Recreate deployment strategy. This can be done in the deployment configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the environment variables mentioned [here](https://github.com/openshift-s2i/s2i-wildfly/blob/master/README.md#example-openshiftwildfly-101-centos7environment-variables) to get a better understanding.